# Character encoding of .netrc

Tags: ftp, character-encoding, .netrc

Does anyone know which character encoding is used in `.netrc`? As a German user, I sometimes put umlauts in passwords.

So my question is, are these treated as latin1 or may I assume that I am doing fine encoding the file in UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no applicable standard for `.netrc`, which started off in the 1980s as a BSD feature.  That of course predates UTF-8.  However, since there are **no** standards, you may be using someone's "improvement" which assumes (a) locale-based encoding or (b) UTF-8.  Don't count on it.

The password used for ftp is covered by an RFC (again, predating UTF-8), and says the content is **ASCII**.  In section 5.3.2, the relevant part of the BNF is

```
        <password> ::= <string>
        <string> ::= <char> | <char><string>
        <char> ::= any of the 128 ASCII characters except <CR> and
        <LF>
```

The later RFCs build on RFC 959, but don't change the rules.  However, implementers stretch things, so you're able to use Latin1.

Further reading:

- [RFC 5797: FTP Command and Extension Registry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5797)
- [RFC 2228: FTP Security Extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2228.txt)
- [RFC 959: FILE TRANSFER PROTOCOL (FTP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) (defines passwords in `ASCII`)
- [Emacs bug#22081: 24.5; netrc.el fails parsing authinfo
  items spread over multiple lines](http://osdir.com/ml/bug-gnu-emacs-gnu/2015-12/msg00168.html)
- [Solaris manpage for .netrc (1990)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0633/6j9vn6q5f/index.html)
- [using .netrc with sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360672/using-netrc-with-sftp)